# How can I get a value from a javascript object when I don't know the property name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have an object `var obj = {id: value}`

In my html, I want to show the id and the value.

I'm using angularjs.

Please: I don't want a solution with ng-repeat, because I get only one element in this object

Thank you

Comment: `obj[ Object.keys(obj).shift() ]`

Comment: silly way: angular.toJson(obj)

Comment: Even with only 1 key:value ng-repeat is still going to be your best and cleanest option. If you are concernd with the number of watches use something to remove the watches such as https://github.com/EnzeyNet/NoBind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a modern browser, you can get a list of an object's "own" property names (not ones from its prototype) via `Object.keys`. If the object has only one property, you'll get back only one name:

```
var name = Object.keys(obj)[0]; // [0] = get the first (only)
```

On older browsers, you can via a `for-in` loop: (Or, you can get a "shim" or "polyfill" for `Object.keys`, which would use one under the covers)

```
var name, n;
for (n in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
        name = n;
        break;
    }
}
```

Once you know the name, you can use that to get the value:

```
var value = obj[name];
```

---

Side note: It's generally best to design objects so that the property names are consistent, and the values vary. So for instance, rather than `{id: value}` where both `id` and `value` are variable, perhaps `{id: "the ID", value: "the value"}` where the property names are consistent and the values vary. Then you could just use `obj.id` and `obj.value`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what your question is. You have an object named obj and which has a property named id.

Do you want to show the value of the property named id? If so, something like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="obj = {id: 'foo'}">
  
  Object id: {{obj.id}}
  
</div>
```

Or is a situation where the object is more like a dictionary, where the property is a variable key?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-init="obj = {bar: 'foo'}; id = 'bar'">
      
  Object {{id}}: {{obj[id]}}
      
</div>
```